# Deleting database value using spring

Tags: spring-mvc, jdbctemplate

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
 Select type of material<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="mango">mango
  <option value="grape">grape
  </select>
  Select weight type<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="Tons">Tons
  <option value="KG">KG
  </select>
 Enter Value<input type="text" >
 <input type="button" value="Enter">
</body>
</html>
```

I want to delete database value in Spring based programming. How can I do 
 this. I want to do this operation in backend. What is the process?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take a look at this [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how to ask or answer questions and to learn more about how stackoverflow works.

Comment: In addition, [ask], will be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

In a Spring based application, database operations such as delete are performed by [Repository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html) classes. Based on your question, I suppose you are "too far" from repository layer. So I suggest you take a [step-by-step tutorial](https://docs.spring.io/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/). It will guide you through all the way down to the business logic and data access.

Another great way to get started with Spring is Spring Boot: [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/) and [here](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-boot-tutorials/)